SSIS package export to Sharepoint site
I have an SSIS package, which exports data to an MS Excel spreadsheet.
I want to upload that MS Excel spreadsheet on to a sharepoint site, within the SSIS Package.
Is there a way of doing this without having to download a third party extension or any extensions.
I have tried OData source in the data flow task however it asks for a user name and password for the connection and when accessing a sharepoint site I dont need one.
